# Transaction internal transaction out of gas?

Tags: out-of-gas

The first error i got was when i was out of gas

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe85ef77ecbfa8faccbe1a4fe3cd270ac304e911ec9a97a5d05dd01c20490421a

Subsequently i tried again after having more ether in my wallet and then this happened.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8df5af265d889b04bd7b4ee55b1c5fc4b4452308f44a892bb1ee49716e4e0756

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x53217cce14d3a09b52e9bf01b558f10b01234dc0576270cb896c81ae04db238f

May i know how do i solve it as i cant transact the item due to multiple internal txns failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Set the Gas limit to 200,000 and any unused gas will be returned to you and your execution will succeed. If it fails, you gotta increase to a higher value.

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet will be to Web3's estimate gas function--while it overestimates sometimes, at least your transaction won't fail :)

Here's a link to docs about it: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/documentation/alchemy-api-reference/json-rpc#eth_estimategas

Comment: Another one that has been flagged as spam. You need to try to answer the question instead of just posting links to Alchemy.